# autofocus in not working in input tag which is not under any form element

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, autofocus

How to set autofocus property in input element which is not a part of a form.
 I have given "autofocus" property in input tag but it is not working.

```
<div>
     //Here I have given the autofocus property
     <input id="text_name" value="name" autofocus /> 
</div>
```

This input is not under any form element.

Comment: And I don't want focus on this input at the time of page load.I need to set focus after some manipulation

Comment: after some manipulation means? after click on some button,after filling some fields, etc..

Comment: so why not try adding the focus using `.focus()` or something like that after the manipulation; where you can "sense" the manipulation using some event listener?

Comment: sorry for incomplete information.some manipulation means after clicking on button

Answer (score 1):

After your manipulation,use Pure Javascript

```
document.getElementById("taxt_name").focus();
```

or jQuery

```
$("#taxt_name").focus();
```